# Optimize search through array in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently working on a piece of code for a school project, wherein we have to lead customers to an available register within a supermarket. Format is that we get first a string with two numbers "x y", where x is the amount of registers and y is the amount of people coming to/leaving a register. Next there is y lines of either "C X" or "L X" format, where "C X" means a customer arrives at register X, and "L X" would be a customer leaving register X. Now if a customer arrives at an empty register it should just print this register number, but if a customer arrives at an already taken register, it should print out the nearest free register, favoring lower numbers (say nr 4 is taken but a customer arrives and both 3 and 5 is free, it should print 3). I'm currently using an array wherein I'm keeping the amount of registers as 0's and then changing these to ones if the register is taken and if it is I then loop through +- 1, +- 2 and so on till I find a free register. However, for a full grade we need to be able to take inputs of up to a million M, and our code needs to execute within a minute and use up a max of 256 mb of memory. Current code is below, I keep hitting the time limit, probably because of the way I iterate over the array, any ideas on how I could optimize this?

```
N, M = map(int, raw_input().split())
entries = []
for x in range(0, M):
    entries.append(raw_input())

registers = []

for x in range(0,M):
    registers.append(0)

for line in entries:
    if line[0] == "L":
        registers[int(line[2])-1] = 0
    elif registers[int(line[2])-1] == 1:
        i = 0
        n = int(line[2])-1
        while True:
            if registers[n-i] == 1:
                pass
            elif n-i >= 0:
                registers[n-i] = 1
                print n-i+1
                break
            if registers[n+i] == 1:
                pass
            else:
                registers[n+i] = 1
                print n+i+1
                break
            i += 1
    else:
        registers[int(line[2])-1] = 1
        print int(line[2])
```

Comment: small gains but list comprehension over append in a loop `registers = [0 for i in range(0,M)]` Maybe look at using numpy arrays for speed.

Comment: Also you map your input to int in the first line and then call int() everytime you use a value which appears redundant